# Export all message from mailbox to eml using Exchange

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, eml

I'd like to export all message from `user mailbox` to `*.eml`. Someone Can help me?

Comment: Did you already right some code? Can you show us your code? Do you have some solution in mind how to tackle the problem?

Comment: You'll have to use EWS or the Outlook COM to save single mail items. Also keep in mind that Outlook can't save to eml (it uses .msg)

Comment: I need export mail from server. My code in Powershell is under.

Answer (score 0):

There is code and an explanation of the issues with exporting Exchange Items as EML files on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn672317(v=exchg.150).aspx#sectionSection2 . The main point to consider is around fidelity and also around different types. Eg if you have a Contact then you can export the contact as Vcard Stream etc, while with Emails what your exporting is the MIME Stream. Exchange has a method of exporting a Mailbox that maintains full fidelity using a PST file via New-MailboxExportRequest https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607299(v=exchg.160).aspx